# How to parse latest entry only (based on index attribute) from an XML in SQL Server 2019 (v15)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I am working on XML files with the following structure. I would like to select the latest entry (this is where d5p1:index="0") of the entries where d5p1:id="W45A" or d5p1:id="W450", while ignoring any older entries.

My desired output would look something like this. Note that I'd ideally also include the W45025 as null, despite it not being included in the latest entry at all:

| Id | Term |
| --- | --- |
| W45A01 | 20211221 |
| W45A02 | 4013072 |
| W45A08 | 4 |
| W45001 | 20211130 |
| W45022 | 4043072 |
| W45023 | 993344 |
| W45024 | 0 |
| W45025 | NULL |

```
<UcSwedishIndividualReport xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Content>
    <status xmlns:d3p1="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" xmlns="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" d3p1:result="ok" />
    <ucReport xmlns="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/">
      <xmlReply>
        <reports xmlns:d5p1="http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/" d5p1:lang="eng">
          <d5p1:report d5p1:id="6002124815" d5p1:name="'FirstName LastName" d5p1:styp="K39" d5p1:index="0">

            <d5p1:group d5p1:id="W45A" d5p1:index="0" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="Credit commitments">
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45A01">20211221</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45A02">4013072</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45A08">4</d5p1:term>
            </d5p1:group>
              
            <d5p1:group d5p1:id="W450" d5p1:index="0" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="Credit commitments">
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45001">20211130</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45022">4043072</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45023">993344</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45024">0</d5p1:term>
            </d5p1:group>
              
            <d5p1:group d5p1:id="W450" d5p1:index="1" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="Credit commitments">
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45001">20210930</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45022">4240629</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45023">1185833</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45024">0</d5p1:term>
            </d5p1:group>
              
            <d5p1:group d5p1:id="W450" d5p1:index="2" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="Credit commitments">
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45001">20210731</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45022">4254142</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45023">1194268</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45024">0</d5p1:term>
              <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W45025">3029874</d5p1:term>
            </d5p1:group>
              
            <d5p1:group d5p1:id="W495" d5p1:index="0" d5p1:key="" d5p1:name="Income info">
               <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W49501">2021</d5p1:term>
               <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W49517">411000</d5p1:term>
               <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W49518">53400</d5p1:term>
               <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W49522">410900</d5p1:term>
               <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W49541">75200</d5p1:term>
               <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W49591">75200</d5p1:term>
               <d5p1:term d5p1:id="W49592">464300</d5p1:term>
            </d5p1:group>
              
          </d5p1:report>
        </reports>
      </xmlReply>
    </ucReport>
  </Content>
</UcSwedishIndividualReport>
```

My current code only grabs all of the values, regardless of their index or of their id. The problem is that I can't differ the old entries from the most recent ones with this method. I've previously tried to differ the values later on by ranking the rows in the order that they were read and then selecting the variables with the lowest row rank, but it seems like the code doesn't always load the table starting from id 0, which breaks my logic.

```
drop table #UC
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/' AS ns,'http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/' AS d5p1)
SELECT ok.*
    ,X.g.value('(@d5p1:id)','varchar(20)') AS id
    ,X.g.value('(text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS term
into #UC
FROM #1 as ok
CROSS APPLY ok.[Message].nodes('UcSwedishIndividualReport/Content/ns:ucReport/ns:xmlReply/ns:reports/ns:report/ns:group/ns:term') X(g)
```

Comment: Do you want the first or the last node in each group? Or how do you define first and last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can use XPath to filter the specific `<d5p1:group>` nodes and their children. Simplified XPath would be:

```
//d5p1:group[@d5p1:id="W45A" or @d5p1:id="W450"][@d5p1:index="0"]/d5p1:term
```

And simplified query:

```sql
SELECT term.value('@d5p1:id', 'varchar(100)') AS id, term.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS term
FROM ... AS t(doc)
CROSS APPLY doc.nodes('//d5p1:group[@d5p1:id="W45A" or @d5p1:id="W450"][@d5p1:index="0"]/d5p1:term') x(term)
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bae2d8960d03e20cb6793f33b23322f)

Comment: Cheers! Is there a way to also bring the index as a new column. For example, a new column called index would be added to my desired output table, which all would have the value 0? I am asking this in case that I would need to bring the second most recent entry too (i.e. index = 1).

Comment: `@index` exist on the `<group>` node but in my example we're selecting its children `<term>` nodes. One trick is to add `term.value('../@d5p1:index', 'varchar(100)') AS [index]` to the select clause.

Comment: Nice! I came up with a slightly different idea, in which I added index=0 as a new column during that first cross apply. I then did that same cross apply with index=1 and added index=1 as a new column, later combining the two tables together.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference particular nodes by their position i.e. `node.[1]` or by their attribute values as in following code:

```
declare @xml xml = '...'

    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/' AS ns,'http://www.uc.se/schemas/ucOrderReply/' AS d5p1)
    SELECT 
         X.g.value('(@d5p1:id)','varchar(20)')  AS id
        ,X.g.value('(text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS term
    
    FROM @xml.nodes('UcSwedishIndividualReport/Content/ns:ucReport/ns:xmlReply/ns:reports/ns:report/ns:group[@d5p1:index="0" and (@d5p1:id="W45A" or @d5p1:id="W450")]') G(n)
    CROSS APPLY G.n.nodes('ns:term') X(g)
```

If you want include id:W45025 in your result set, it should be presented in xml as empty node. The other way is to join result of above query to table with full list of id's you want.

Comment: That's extremely helpful, thanks!